# in an HTML forms - how to underline text with non-text color?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I would like to have black text in my forms which is underlined in red.
The problem with using  `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` is, that it underlines not only the text but the whole length of my input button. The button has neither border nor background if not active. Thus it looks strange, if the line is overlapping by 5px or so on each side...

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="doSthFancy" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id}" />
    <input type="submit" value="${item.name} (${item.producer})" class="link" />
</form>
```

Nesting with divs (`<div class="redUnderline"><p class="blackText"> hello world! </p></div>`) usually works, but it seems as if only outside of forms.

I can't use hrefs instead.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the button doesn't have any background colors or borders, than you can just adjust the width of the button to be only as wide as the text?

Comment: Separate the text from the buttons?

Comment: @reinder no, it gets a background color when hovered or active

Comment: @David but then the text is no link any more, isn't it? I need the underlining to indicate that you can click it ;)

Comment: Oh, I see. Gareth already answered it, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a `fake button`?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/9cpx5/)

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform">
    <div id="fakeButton" onclick="myform.submit()">
        <span>Click Me</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#fakeButton
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    background-color:#808080;
    width:70px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;

}
#fakeButton span
{
    color:black;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:red;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

Comment: with `onclick="javascript:this.parentNode.submit();"` it works fine! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

How about a button, and spans? I tried this:

```
<button style="padding: 20px;"><span style="border-bottom: dotted 1px red;">some text</span></button>
```

and it seemed to work. The dotted red border only underlined the text.

Comment: this i nice! :) But how could the button be attached to the form? (I have to send a few hidden values). This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp) apparently does not work for IE. :(